# Does Mysql locks table while insert operation

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am using Mysql(INNODB) and does Mysql locks table when I do some insert operation?

I have a huge table and it has lots of indexes. I do some research and Mysql doc says INNODB only locks rows not the entire table but I have indexes and does it still only locks rows? My insert queries nearly takes 36 seconds.

```
Query_time: 35.829970
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

InnoDB will only lock the row.  But it will eventually have to update all the indexes; however this is mostly deferred.

Was something else going on while the `INSERT` was taking 36 seconds?  Perhaps a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`?  Or even a `SELECT` can block the `INSERT` in certain circumstances.

Next time it happens, quickly do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to see what else is running.  Then do `SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS` to (hopefully) get some info specific to the `INSERT` and why it is blocked.

What version are you running?  Newer versions have tables to help get more info, even after the fact.

Comment: Rick, you have saved one life 3 years and half later. Really thank you. :-)